# UrlFetchApp is returning 403 response codes even when its IPs are whitelisted? (March 2020)

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

We run a stock checker on our site reliant on the HTTP response codes that we get via UrlFetchApp. Since last week, these have been returning 403's roughly 25% of the time. We got our client to whitelist the UrlFetchApp IPs, but unfortunately this has not resolved it.

Not quite sure what to do here? Has anyone else been experiencing this and found a solution?

Here is the piece of code of the request that is returning this 403 error:

```js
function httpresponse( uri ) {
   var response_code ;
   try {
      response_code = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, { followRedirects: false }).getResponseCode().toString() ;
      }
   catch( error ) {
      response_code = error.toString().match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
      }
   finally { return response_code ; }
   
}
```

Thanks,
Leon

Comment: 403 forbidden and 401 unauthorized are usually associated with the logged-in user.. is this all public traffic?

Comment: @tehhowch - Have tried this from a variety of accounts, I was under the assumption that it goes through the UrlFetchApp IPs as a proxy of sorts

Comment: Could you please share a sample piece of your code and of your request to make sure everything is set as expected?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - Here's the excerpt that pulls the response codes;

Comment: function httpresponse( uri )  
{  
  var response_code ;  
  try {  
    response_code = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, { followRedirects: false })  
 .getResponseCode() .toString() ;  
  }  
  catch( error ) {  
    response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;  
  }  
  finally {  
    return response_code ;  
  }  
}

Comment: Being logged in to Google to run the script does not mean you make authenticated HTTP calls. Are these URLs protected by any authentication mechanism? Authorization header? URL querystring parameter? Etc.

Comment: Are you using URLs or URIs? Because I can see the parameter naming is ```uri``` and ```UrlFetchApp.fetch()``` exclusively works with URLs.